# How to update model using query parameters and partially reloading route's DOM tree

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a route that has a form with some search fields (e.g. code, name, and so on) and a table that updates results while the user types something on these fields.

I have made all form fields bound to its respective query parameter on controller. So, when ember propagates the fields values to the URI, the parameters the route reloads the model making the table to be updated. So far so good.

But, there is a side effect on this design, when the user types Ember reloads the entire route's DOM tree making the user to lose the focus on the field.

So, I would like to know how I could make only the table with the results to be updated while the user continually types whatever he needs on the form fields.

They are all on the same route's HBS with some components.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to split it into two routes:

1. One route that shows your input fields. This routes controller holds the variables for the input-binidings.
2. a subroute that handles the queryParams by listening to changes on the parent controller and shows the results accordingly.

For the subroutes controller you could do something like this:

```
needs: ['fieldscontroller'],
// or fieldscontroller: Ember.inject.controller() if your are on a newer Ember version
code: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.fieldscontroller.code'),
name: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.fieldscontroller.name'),
// or name: Ember.computed.alias('fieldscontroller.name') on newer Ember versions
```

This way, only your subroute (with the results) would reload on changes made in the parent route.

Comment: Got it! I'll try that! Thank you!